# What software I'll need to become proficient in the Microsoft endorsed languages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, javascript

I have a free MSDN account and now that I am proficient in C/C++/Java, and know some JavaScript, PHP and MySQL, I want to learn some proprietary languages from Microsoft. I am looking to experiment with everything within the next several months - C#, ASP, VB, things I haven't even heard of [insert suggestions here], what have you.

However, I know nothing about the languages and the software that I need. I don't even know what .NET is.

I don't know if I should be downloading Visual Studio 2008 or Visual Studio .NET. I don't know if I need .NET Framework 1.1... there's just so much stuff on MSDN. I don't even know how begin to do any ASP... Please don't flame me.

I was hoping that with your help I can make a complete list of languages and software and start experimenting. Which framework do I need? Should I install a regular Windows, a professional version or a server? What do I need to do DB related stuff?

There are a lot of questions here and I would like to get an answer to each, so please contribute with whatever you can. I am devoting 2 days to downloading and researching the topic myself, but I would like some [professional] people input, because googling these things just isn't enough.

Comment: One question at a time is a good plan.

Comment: *proprietary* makes it all sound so dirty... You won't get much done it 2 days. It will help to define a clear objective

Comment: In 2 days I am just researching what languages there are and what software to download. I could devote more if need be. I have 6+ months to experiment with the languages themselves.

Comment: "Proprietary" is not a term I'd apply to a platform and languages that have ECMA standards and open source implementations. http://www.mono-project.com

Comment: I removed the term Proprietary from the title

Comment: "Visual Studio .NET" on MSDN is the 2003 version.  Don't use it!

Answer (score 9):

A good start would be **Visual Studio 2008**. This is the IDE and is the current version.

The installer will make sure that you have the correct versions of .NET installed, and also includes the database **SQL Express**.

You can install this on any version of Windows later than Windows XP Service Pack 2.

Since you come from a Java/C/C++ background, you may find **C#** most similar to what you are used to.

Personally, I would ignore VB.NET and look at **F#** next. However, that is not included in Visual Studio before 2010, but you can download a preview for free that works with Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 3):

The express editions are a good start, they are free. the install should install any dependencies you need (the run time etc). There are plenty of other add ons (ASP.NET MVC is currently an add on for anything less than the 2010 beta of Visual Studio).

I included a link for the 2008 express editions which are the most current released versions

[Visual Studio Express 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/exPress/download/)

Comment: Actually, ASP.NET MVC comes w/ VS 2008 SP1

Answer (score 2):

I agree w/ the poster who said you need to focus your efforts.  First question: are you trying to learn this for developing for the web, or for desktop?

If Web, learn ASP.NET, if not, not.

Under ASP.NET, are you planning on just trying it out to get something up quickly, or do you want something more long-term, possibly leveraging your PHP/MySQL/JS skills?  If the former, go for "regular" ASP.Net (aka Webforms), otherwise, go MVC (which will probably seem more familiar coming from PHP).

As far as languages, that comes down to preference, they're pretty interchangeable.  I prefer C#, and if you're good at Java that may be true for you as well.

Tools, if you have an MSDN subscription, then Visual Studio 2008 Pro (or Team) is the way to go, get the latest SP's and you're up and running.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

MS-SQL Server 2008 along with .Net 3.5 would be a couple of other suggestions that I think may be worth tossing out there.  The SQL Server is Microsoft's relational DB that may be worth learning a little so that you could compare it to MySQL in some ways if you are into relational DB stuff.  The .Net 3.5 is the latest version of the framework and may not be a bad idea to begin with some of the newer functionality within the framework with things like LINQ for example.